# iOS 8 today widget - UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, ios-app-extension, today-extension

Is it possible to add something like an UIAlertView to a today widget? I added an IBAction an an UIAlertView to the Widget but nothing happened.

And ist it possible to make a bigger widget? I changed the height in the Size-Inspector but it didn't work at all.

Comment: `UIAlertView`s and `UIActionSheet`s have been deprecated you now have use `UIAlertController`

Comment: Do you have an example? It won't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, you cannot show an alert in a today widget. UIAlertControllers are presented modally, and your widget does not have access to the entire screen. It has about 3/4 of the screen height maximum to display in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some basic code to do this in swift (for future projects):

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: UIAlertControllers are presented full-screen and cannot be used in today widgets

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `UIAlertController`on iOS8, the reference is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/).

For instance:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"AlertView" message:@"I am an AlertView" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                          [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                      }];
[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Actually if you try to do this in a Today App Extension Widget, you get this at runtime: 

2014-08-25 16:42:21.994 LauncherWidget[76137:2316933] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Feature not available in extensions of type com.apple.widget-extension'

Comment: Yeah sorry this worked in beta but it no longer works